# Discord.js; why does this not add the role?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm quite new to Stack Overflow, so excuse me if I do something wrong.

I've been working on Discord bots lately, and for my server I want to make a verification bot. I've got a large piece of the code all done and dusted, but now the important part doesn't work, and I don't know why.

My code:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client({ partials: ["MESSAGE", "CHANNEL", "REACTION"]});
const prefix = "v!";

client.on("ready", async () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`);
    client.user.setActivity("v!verify | Verify in #┃verify-here", {type: "LISTENING"});
});

client.on("message", async(msg) => {
    const args = msg.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(' ');
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === 'svm') { // svm = send verification message
        if (msg.member.id !== '434239200607600651') return;

        const sEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("Welcome to **aSpiv's Network**!")
        .setDescription("aSpiv's Network is a place to hang out, talk and have fun with friends, family and strangers. Our goal is to make this community as friendly and welcoming as possible. Please, remember the human.")
        .addField(" Community Guidelines", "TL;DR Use common sense. If you think you'll get a warning for it, don't do it!\n\nTreat everyone with respect. This is the #1 rule of this server. Absolutely no harassment, witch hunting, sexism, racism, or hate speech will be tolerated.\n\nNo spam or self-promotion (server invites, advertisements, etc) without permission from a staff member. This includes DMing fellow members.\n\nNo NSFW or obscene content. This includes text, images, or links featuring nudity, sex, hard violence, or other graphically disturbing content. (Except for the places where it's allowed; see at own risk!)\n\nTalk English. We want to make sure everyone can participate in all conversations, so no one feels left out.\n\nDon't earrape in the voice chats. It's annoying for people who actually want to talk.\n\nNo voice changers. If you don't want people to hear your voice, then don't talk at all.\n\nIf you see something against the rules or something that makes you feel unsafe, let staff know. We want this server to be a welcoming place!")
        .addField(" Getting Verified", "To agree to the rules and receive permission to view all of our channels and send messages, go to <#792391986799837224> and send \`v!verify\`. You are responsible for reading the contents of this channel before agreeing. By being in this server, you agree to all our rules. These rules are subject to change.\n\naSpiv's Network or aSpiv Staff can not and will not be held responsible for any damages or losses that result from the use of our server. We will help you out the best we can, but we are only humans, too.")
        .setColor(Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215))
        msg.channel.send(sEmbed)

        msg.delete();
    }

    if(command === 'verify') {
        let sEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("Get Verified")
        .setDescription("Click on the emoji below to get verified! Make sure you've read the embed in <#791281485276905492>!")
        .setColor(Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215))

        let m = await msg.channel.send(sEmbed)
        m.react('✅')
    }

    return;
});

client.on("messageReactionAdd", async(reaction, user) => {
    if(reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
    if(reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();

    if(user.client) return;
    if(!reaction.message.guild) return;
    
    if(reaction.emoji.name === '✅') {
        await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(r => r.id === "792395200676495371")
    }
})

client.login("n0t.4-r3al_t0k3n")
```

Does anyone see the mistake here? It should send a message, react to that message with ✅  (That part works), but when I react with the message too, it should give me a role, but it doesn't.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Problem**

The issue is in your `messageReactionAdd` event handler, which I assume you must already know given the only part of your code that isn't working is the code's response to your reaction. In that part of your code, you are doing `if (user.client) return;`. This line is incorrect, and will *always* return (because `user.client` is always true).

I'm guessing you want to return if the user that reacted is a bot. But `user.client` doesn't return whether or not the user is a bot; it returns the `Client` that created the `user` variable. Essentially, it returns your `client` variable. And since the `User` object stored in the `user` variable is always created by your client, that `if` statement will always return and prevent your actual role-adding code from occurring (just like what `if (true) return;` would do).

**The Solution**

Here's how to fix it, such that it actually checks if the user is a bot or not instead of trying to check if the client exists or not:

```
client.on("messageReactionAdd", async(reaction, user) => {
    if(reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
    if(reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();

    if(user.bot) return;
    if(!reaction.message.guild) return;
    
    if(reaction.emoji.name === '✅') {
        await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(r => r.id === "792395200676495371")
    }
})
```

Simply changing `user.client` to `user.bot` will solve your issue, or will at the very least allow your role-adding code to actually run and allow you to see if there are any additional errors.

**Relevant Resources**

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=bot
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=client

Comment: Thank you! It did indeed give me another error, but it was easy to fix. Once again thanks for helping me <3

Comment: No problem! Consider clicking the green checkmark and marking this answer as the accepted answer if it helped you out, as it will let anyone with the same problem in the future know that this is the correct answer :D